# Solving a bilinear form equation over a cubic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

(This question was asked earlier on math stack exchange, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687760/solving-a-bilinear-form-equation-over-a-cubic-field)

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic cubic field, i.e., $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois cubic extension. Consider the bilinear form defined on $K^2$ by

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 2 x_2 y_0 - x_1 y_1 + 2 x_0 y_2,$$

where $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, x_1, x_2)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (y_2, y_1, y_0)$.

Is there a solution to the equation

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0$$

with entries of $\mathbf{x}$ being conjugates of the entries of $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ not proportional to $\mathbb{Q}$-vectors?